# How to make right looping through while?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to make looping. I want an output of number from 1-10 squared.

What is wrong, below?

```
for num in range(1, 10):
  print (num)
  while num < 100:
    num = num ** 2
  print(str(num))
```

Comment: `num` will always be less than `10`, so your `while` loop will never exit

Comment: @ Patrick Haugh 
Could you check it now

Comment: Why can't you just `print(num ** 2)`?

Comment: While this could be done with a `while` loop, a single `for` loop by itself would be sufficient (and you certainly don't need both).

Answer (score 1):

Printing 1 to 10 squared would be like this:

```
 for num in range(1,11):
     print (num ** 2)
```

But if you wanted to print the number first and then the squared result you could do it like this

```
 for num in range(1,11):
      print (str(num) + ": " + str(num ** 2))
```

These are only suggestions, hope I helped!